# Is there a way to just create a link that is only used for its onClick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I’m trying to create a link that could be used by my jquery to append another ActionLink somewhere on the page.  I don’t want to call a controller or navigate to somewhere on the page.  I want my jquery to create the link using append.

I’ve tried different overloads and the only one I found that did not navigate away from the page was this:

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink(stdFName,"Action","Controller",null,new { teacher = "Teacher Name", @class = "className", id = stdNum });
```

It doesn’t call a controller and it appends the link as I want.  I’m just not sure that this is the best way to do it.

Here’s the script that executes when the link is clicked:

```
 $("#174").on("click", function () {



        var newElems = $("<div class='studentInfo'></div")
    .append('@Html.ActionLink("Student Name", "StudentInformation","TeacherStudent", new { rope="said" },null)')

        $("#redAlertRow").append(newElems);

    });
```

Is there a way to just create a link that is only used for its onClick event?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Probably this

```
       var routeurl = '@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")';
       window.location.href = routeurl;
```

cheers.